# How to add another Ubuntu version to "affects" list on Launchpad bug?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

I experience that bug on Precise: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1212142

So far it has been reported that it affects Saucy. I want to add Precise to "affects" list. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I entered the same bug site being logged out and I noticed that there is another button, which was not visible when I was logged in: "Nominate for series".

[image: Nominate for series]

Judging from its icon I suspect that it is what I am looking for. However, it appears that I do not have permissions to nominate this bug, so it does not appear when I am logged in.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is another link called "Nominate for release", which is supposed to be available for only bug administrators, according to this [mailing list discussion](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2012-August/263301.html) and this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/253597). Since neither of us are one, the best option is to leave a comment noting that it still affects 12.04.

Comment: It tried but it does not work that way. After clicking 'Also affects distribution/package' I can select another package or Linux distrubution (Arch, Fedora, etc.). However, another Ubuntu releases are not on the list.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain.

Comment: I downvoted. First version of your answer was wrong. Moreover, I provided the [right answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/511912/256489) first. Ten minutes after that you completely edited your answer to include my solution. Furthermore, your edition made my [former comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/511878/how-to-add-another-ubuntu-version-to-affects-list-on-launchpad-bug/511894?noredirect=1#comment692378_511894) senseless.

Comment: @PiotrJurkiewicz I didn't see your answer since I was editing on the app. It took the best part of fifteen minutes for me to look up sources to corroborate it. Comments become outdated, that is in their nature - indeed you can even flag them as being so. You can always accept your own answer, there's no need to downvote a perfectly OK answer. Doing so is just insulting my attempt to help you. Worse, one doesn't downvote without an explanation. That is just rude.